# How to Launch MySQL shell script

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am testing MySQL Workbench as I could gather from the docs one way to launch MySQL from Windows Command Line as per:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.0/en/windows-start-command-line.html is to look for the file installed with MySQL called "mysqld"

Now I could find the .exe file "mysqld", however when I double click it flashes and disappears.

Any idea or suggestions?

I am able to launch MySQL from its own icon, but not from the file above mentioned.

Using workbench 6.1 community

Answer (score 0):

You are totally confusing the MySQL server (which mysqld.exe is) and MySQL Workbench (MySQLWorkbench.exe, another application). The MySQL command line client (which is totally independent of MySQL Workbench) can be started by opening a command window (cmd.exe) and running `mysql` from there (not `mysqld`). But as this is independent from MySQL Workbench (which is just another client, even though a much more sophisticated one), you need to call the MySQL Workbench executable if you want to run it. If you do that from a command prompt it will spit out a number of parameters you can use.